Etiquette for getting slides/notes from professor who missed a presentation
I attended a seminar recently where there was supposed to be a scheduled talk given by a professor, which I really wanted to hear. However, this professor ended up not showing up, so I did not hear the talk. I'd like to email them and see if they have any planned slides or notes for the talk that they would be able to share. Something a long the lines of Hi Dr._ I was really looking forward to your talk but missed it, do you have any notes on what you planned to speak about that you would be able to share.
What would the most polite way of going about this be?

Do you know why they missed their talk?

No, I don't know what the reason was

Maybe "willing" in place of "able", but seems perfectly polite to me.

I would say that it's perfectly fine to ask. If they have some notes that will probably send them, if not, they will probably not feel pressured to write some just for you. In any case there is a good chance for a nice email exchange.

Might be useful to include a line like, "I was really looking forward to hearing you speak . I'm not sure what prevented your talk, but if you happened to have prepared some notes or slides on what you were going speak about and are willing to share, I'd love to be able to review them." Not keen to write a separate answer, since I don't have much to add otherwise.
